# Copypicture doesn' work with the cell range marked by numbers

Tags: excel, vba, format, range

I'm working on a code which copies a range content to the clipboard as a picture. It works perfectly well when I use the letters and numbers to describe a range:

```
Call Worksheets("Traces_condenses").Range("A1:AC35").CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)
```

However, when I try to replace it with the range described by cell numbers, it fails with the app-defined or object-defined error (1004):

```
Call Worksheets("Traces_condenses").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(2, 1)).CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)
```

Could you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong? 
Thank you in advance,
Jan

Comment: Specify worksheets of these cells

Comment: This has been covered many times before. Fully qualify your Cell object as @Teamothy mentioned else `Cells(1, 1)` will always refer to the active sheet and the active sheet may not be Worksheets("Traces_condenses") which will cause the error.

Comment: As suggested previously, something like `Call Worksheets("Traces_condenses").Range(Worksheets("Traces_condenses").Cells(1, 1), Worksheets("Traces_condenses").Cells(2, 1)).CopyPicture(xlScreen, xlPicture)` should work

Comment: Thank you very much, of course it works well!