# Excel VBA “Autofill Method of Range Class Failed”

Tags: excel, vba

The following VBA code is failing with Error 1004, "Autofill Method of Range Class Failed.". It works great in the first Worksheet(i = 9), but on the next one it fails after `Worksheets(i).Cells(Cel.Row, 6).Value = 0`

```
Dim LastRow As Long


For i = 9 To 24 Step 1

LastRow = Worksheets(i).Cells(Worksheets(i).Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Worksheets(i).Range("C2:E" & LastRow).FillDown
Worksheets(i).Range("G2:G" & LastRow).FillDown

    Set DniRange = Worksheets(i).Range("E2:E" & LastRow)

        For Each Cel In DniRange.Cells
            If Cel.Value = "0" Then
            Worksheets(i).Cells(Cel.Row, 6).Value = 0
            Worksheets(i).Cells(Cel.Row, 6).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Cel.Row, 6), Cells(LastRow, 6)), Type:=xlFillSeries
            Worksheets(i).Cells(Cel.Row, 6).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(Cel.Row, 6), Cells(2, 6)), Type:=xlFillSeries
            End If
        Next Cel
    Next
```

Any ideas guys?

Comment: See the Comments in [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59193463/copypicture-doesn-work-with-the-cell-range-marked-by-numbers) question

Comment: Hint: `Destination:=Range([???]Cells(Cel.Row, 6), [???]Cells(`

Comment: Your code would get the same result if you tested for "0" from the last row up, and use `Exit For` after you run into the first "0" . This would only use `AutoFill` once, not for each "0" in the column.